# .getRange RC notation Issue

Tags: google-apps-script

The first code below works as expected, but with the second one I got the following error message:Exception: `The parameters (String,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange`. Why? And how do I fix that?

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  range = sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(10);
}

function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  range = sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(10);
}
```

Comment: Spreadsheet and sheet are different classes and have different methods.

Comment: There is no method `.getRange(row,column)` for Class Spreadsheet